# WebAPI with too long query string from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, api

I came into a situation where my front-end code has a javascript call like the following:
window.location.href = baseUrl + "token="+[jwt]
this redirection is intended to download a file. Now with the time my jwt grew very lengthy(more than 2000 char) and it is start throwing error 404 - resource not found. The API is stable and I don't want to change on it. I tried with $.redirect and it is posting data but download did not happen.
my api now looks like

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("MyMethod")]
        public HttpResponseMessage MyMethod([FromUri] string token = null, [FromUri] string id = null)
        {
            return internalMethodtodownloadFile(token, id, false);
        }
```

I changed to

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("MyMethod")]
    public HttpResponseMessage MyMethod([FromBody] string token = null, [FromBody] string id = null)
    {
        return internalMethodtodownloadFile(token, id, false);
    }
```

Any help.

Comment: Usually jwt token values are sent in the http header. Why not do that?

Comment: Could you please help me to understand how can I add the header in window.location.href

Comment: Don't use `window.location.href` to download a file. There are other ways to do this without using `window.location.href`. See [download a file javascript](https://www.google.com/search?q=download+a+file+javascript+site:stackoverflow.com). You could also pass in the token as a form field (instead of header).

Comment: My API (ASP.NET web API) method is already doing this. and this is working for the short URL and code is in production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using window.location.href + token, you are using GET-Request, and it respectively has maximal length of 2048 characters. If you would use POST-Request, there will be no limit.

Comment: It is working for my all other request but not in that only instance where my request is downloading a file. So I got stuck here. I want something work around like Igor mentioned but not sure how to do it.